# 502 Bad Gateway - Laravel - Nginx - Valet

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

today I check a site (before it worked) and I get 502 Bad Gateway when I get data from Salesforce.

I do a `dd($response);` and I got all the data, 0 errors, 0 Laravel errors, all look ok. But when put a `return view()` after that I get the 502 Bad Gateway.

I check nginx errors and 0 errors in .log, Laravel log 0 errors too.
If I tried in Apache it works normally, and if I do `php artisan serve` it work too. Only happens in Nginx.

In controllers where the API is not called it works and show the view and data correctly. Only happens when I realice a API's call, but all responses are ok, so weird.

I'm ussing:

- Valet 2.9.0
- Laravel 6.18
- Nginx/1.17.9

Any suggestion that what could be?

Thanks

Comment: Does Salesforce have a configuration to determine the source of client URL?

Comment: Yup. All configured. It worked last week, today nope

Comment: Can you get error message information from Salesforce? The `502` error message can be caused by different factors.

Comment: 0 errors too. As I said, when I do a `dd($response)` (from Salesforce) i got all results. I try the same query in a pure PHP file with 'valet link' and it works :s. Maybe is the Laravel project, dunno

Comment: Okay. And what's your valet URL?

Comment: Now is `salesforce.test`, and the pure PHP is `testweird.test`. I can't show it with ngrox or anything because info

Comment: Have you added the site under "Remote Site Settings" on Salesforce?

Comment: Yup. All configured

Comment: I can only guess that it can only be accessed by `http://localhost`. I am wondering if you have added `http://salesforce.test` on Salesforce.

Comment: Yup, it is added. Anyway, I'm using sandbox and login with pass+token without callback for now, and `testweird.test` is not added and it works. But the main domain (salesforce.test) is added from first day.

Comment: hey! have you been able to resolve this?